# Remove a node that doesn't have attribute

Tags: asp.net, xml

I've using asp.net, and I've got an xml file provided from a third party website. I want it to be scraped so it only display the first main node. My problem is there is no attribute on any of the node. How can I manage to remove them?

The following is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<offers>
  <class_offer>
    <name><![CDATA[Learn to surf and save 52% at Muriwai Surf School]]></name>
    <url>http://domain.co.nz/wai-surf-school-just-29</url>
    <location>Auckland</location>
  </class_offer>
  <class_offer>
    <name><![CDATA[$35 for a 30 minute luxury Slipper Bath experience for TWO]]></name>
    <url>http://domain.co.nz/uxury-slipper-bath-experience-for-two</url>
    <location>Auckland</location>
  </class_offer>
  <class_offer>
    <name><![CDATA[Save 52% at Te Aroha Mineral Spas]]></name>
    <url>http://domain.co.nz/rience-for-two-PLUS-massage</url>
    <location>Auckland</location>
  </class_offer>
</offers>
```

And I want it to be this below,only keeps the first  (the last 2 `"<class_offer>"` has been removed, and `"<location>"` has been removed)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<offers>
  <class_offer>
    <name><![CDATA[Learn to surf and save 52% at Muriwai Surf School]]></name>
    <url>http://domain.co.nz/wai-surf-school-just-29</url>
  </class_offer>
</offers>
```

I really have no idea what to do to remove without the attribute in the node. If anyone could help that'll be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
XElement firstNode = root.Element("offers").Elements().First();
firstNode.Element("location").Remove();
foreach(XElement x in root.Element("offers").Elements().Skip(1))
  x.Remove();
```